# NextJs app build as a dependency in another nextjs app

Tags: javascript, next.js13

How to add a nextjs app build as a dependency in another nextjs app.

I just tried installing the branch as a dependency. But it had lot of dependencies as I am installing a complete app. Is there any way in which we can achieve the same in simple way.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best bet is probably to house both apps inside a [monorepo](https://monorepo.tools/) and factor out the code you'd like to share between the two apps into a package that both depend on. NextJS apps aren't designed to be embedded within one another unless you're looking to host one on a separate domain and embed via an iframe or something.

Vercel's [Turborepo](https://turbo.build/repo/docs/getting-started/create-new) may be of some assistance in declaring dependencies between your two apps and any common code they share.

Comment: Hi Dennis, Thanks for your reply. Can we use gut submodule? Is there any issue with that approach.

Comment: The goal with a monorepo would be to put all of your applications under the same git repository so you don't have to worry about application code getting out of sync between different repositories, but there's theoretically nothing that would stop you from using a git submodule for one or more of your packages.